# Split the JDBC Oracle Resultset to avoid OOM error

Tags: java, oracle, memory, jdbc

I have a program that connects through JDBC to an oracle database and extracts 3+ Million records. If I load everything into memory I am getting an out of memory error. I want to load the data into memory into parts of 50000.

There is two ways that I am approaching the issue:
a) Keep the connection open and process the data into groups of 50 0000 as they come from the result set. 
I do not really like this approach because there could be a risk of leaving the connection open when everything is done and also the connection could be open for a long time (risking timeouts and decreasing connections pool) as each group of 50 000 records is being processed (and by being processed I mean each of these could cause other connections to open and close quickly based on the derived data that may be needed)
b) Process based on row numbers but I am not sure what the impact might be if the underplaying data changes and also I cannot really afford to do a sort every time I process 50 000 records.

This seems to be a common problem and I would like to know what are some industry standards/ best approaches/ design patterns to this issue.

Comment: As far as I know Oracle by default doesn't keep all fetched rows in memory. Are you by any chance using a scrollable result set instead of a type forward only? Or are you yourself storing that much in memory?

Comment: That is correct, oracle does not keep all in memory, and they are referenced by the ResultSet object. But to keep a reference to the resultset oject I need to keep the connection open in java and I am wondering if there is a better approach then keeping the connection open. If I load everything into memory myself I will get a guaranteed out of memory.

Comment: I would assume your program is keeping everything in memory (or not releasing the processed data correctly) I have successfully exported 100 million rows through JDBC without even increasing the default heap size.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a durable transaction that spans the entire read (aka no one changing data out from under you, which you allude to), you might want to investigate moving this problem to the rdbms, and coding it as a stored procedure that you can call from jdbc/jpa/whatever.

i know it doesn't solve it from the java side, but sometimes moving the problem IS the proper solution, depending on context and details.

cheers